# Position glyphicon just below a label

Tags: css, glyphicons

I'm trying to create a custom label just like this photo [image]

My idea is to postion this [glyphicon](http://fontawesome.io/icon/sort-desc/) down there ,but I don't know exactly how. Here is what I have right now : [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/OmarIsComing/hVn5AVCbF0)

Comment: This may help you http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Comment: thanks , it helped a lot.

Comment: Glad to know that :-)